# Angular can not find my factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

So I created with angular a small factory to get my local json file now I wanna pass that data to my controller but it can't find the factory name and says 'unresolved variable'.

Here is the snippet of my code what I guess is relevant for now.

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('locatieTool', ['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('teamController', function ($scope) {
        function init () {
            dataFactory.getTeams().success(function(data) {
                $scope.teams = data
            });
        }
        init();
        console.log($scope.teams);
    });

    // factory
    app.factory('dataFactory', function($http) {
        var team = {};

        //get local data
        team.getTeams = function() {
            return $http.get ('http://localhost:4040/');
        };
        return team;
    });

})();
```

My goal is just to console log the $scope.teams, than I can do more with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should include "dataFactory" inside your controller

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('locatieTool', ['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('teamController', function ($scope, dataFactory) {
        function init () {
            dataFactory.getTeams().success(function(data) {
                $scope.teams = data
            });
        }
        init();
        console.log($scope.teams);
    });

    // factory
    app.factory('dataFactory', function($http) {
        var team = {};

        //get local data
        team.getTeams = function() {
            return $http.get ('http://localhost:4040/');
        };
        return team;
    }); })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to pass your factory into the controller:

```
app.controller('teamController', function ($scope, dataFactory) {
    function init () {
        dataFactory.getTeams().success(function(data) {
            $scope.teams = data
        });
    }
    init();
    console.log($scope.teams);
});
```